# C macro generating strings by character code

Tags: c, string, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm working with a game engine that uses escape codes in strings to perform commands such as setting color. eg to set the color to red, you write `"Red text:\x81\xFF\x00\x00\xFFhello!"` (0x81, red, green, blue, alpha).

Is it possible to create a macro like `TEXT_COLOR(r,g,b,a)` such that `TEXT_COLOR(255,0,0,255)` would expand to `"\x81\xFF\x00\x00\xFF"` for use in constant strings?

Comment: You can certainly do it with `TEXT_COLOR(FF,00,00,FF)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a mix of token pasting and stringification in different macros, but, yeah, it's possible using base-16 numbers:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEXT_COLOR2(r,g,b,a) "\x81" #r #g #b #a
#define TEXT_COLOR(r,g,b,a) TEXT_COLOR2(\x ##r, \x ##g, \x ##b, \x ##a)

int main(void) {
  char s[] = "Red text:" TEXT_COLOR(FF, 00, 00, FF) "hello!";
  for (const char *c = s; c < s + sizeof(s); c++) {
    printf("\\x%02hhX", *c);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```