# Convert a C character to the namesake escaped character

Tags: c, escaping, c-preprocessor, special-characters

Is there a way to define *one* C preprocessor macro that takes a C character and expands to the namesake escaped character? For example, `macro(n)` would expand to `'\n'` and `macro(b)` would expand to `'\b'`.

Comment: Leave out the quotes and you can use the same technique as in [the answer I just gave to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619778/c-macro-generating-strings-by-character-code) to get a string literal.

Comment: You want `macro(a)  (a == 'n' ? '\n' : a == 'r' ? '\r' : .... )`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Functionally, yes. But is there a way to build an escaped character token from the original character token?

Comment: @Shawn I do not want a string literal. I want a character.

Comment: If you have `'n'` tokens you can't "insert" a token between `'` and `n`. If you want to have `' \ n '` tokens where `n` is parameterized, I believe that is not possible. How would you use that macro anyway? Why not just write `'\n'`?

Comment: @KamilCuk "I believe that is not possible." I can confirm that it's not; briefly, there's no way to break the character sequence `'\n'` into two smaller sequences that are themselves preprocessing-tokens, so there's no way to use paste to build it.  (Note e.g. that there's language in the standard explicitly forbidding `'` from being a token on its own).

Comment: @HWalters Thank you, it makes sense. Perhaps you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can join to a macro that expands to that character literal:

```
#define macro_b()  '\b'
#define macro_n()  '\n'
#define macro(x)   macro_##x()
macro(n)  // expands to '\n'
macro(b)  // expands to '\b'
```

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for making `macro_n` a function-like macro instead of an object-like one?

Comment: These macros work only for `'\n'` but not for other characters (e.g., not for `'\b'`). The question was if I could have _one_ macro that works for any character.

Comment: @JohnBolinger No. (Except, like, there is a possibility someone makes `int macro_n = 1`). It can be a normal macro.

Comment: @DYZ soooo... add them? `#define macro_b() '\b'`. etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's not what I asked for, sorry.